# Why future tense? “This is the last time he’s going to stand me up”

Tags: grammar, tenses, future

Why does the second part of the phrase use future tense? Although the event “the last time” is happening now, we refer to it using future tense. It also works with “will:”

“This is the last time he will stand me up.”

Any ideas?

Comment: Because the action (of standing me up) has not taken place yet.

Comment: It's possible the speaker has just been stood up and is complaining about it. In which case, the future tense makes sense because she's saying that even though it's happening now, it won't happen again (in the future)

Comment: What’s funny, is that when you hear this, you know that it isn’t true, don’t you? You just **know** he *is* going to stand her up’ - again and again. So maybe that’s why it’s in the present tense.

Comment: No, you know he will stand her up again *if given the chance to*.

Comment: Could you please explain why you have a problem with this, together some account of how you have tried to find this out for yourself?  This is what is expected of questions in ELU.  Have you considered the possibility that the future tense is  used because the speaker is asserting that there will in future be no more standing up (after this one, because in future the speaker will not agree to a date).

Answer (score 1):

In this sentence, it is stated that in the future he will not perform the action of "stand me up", even though the sentence is being said in the present. The sentence is informing about the action which might/might not happen in the future. That is the reason why it is written in the future format.

Answer (score 1):

"This is the last time he will/is going to stand me up.” is a prediction.

Let us assume that he has stood the girl up three times:

The first time that he stood the girl up was not the last time.'

The second time was not the last time.

The girl is saying that this time, i.e. the third time **is going to be/will be** the last time, because there is going to be/will be no fourth time when he will stand her up.

Comment: Agreed, noting that there is an implication he will not be given any further opportunities to stand her up.